# Handle threads between classes with C++, libvlc and ubuntu

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, libvlc

I have an application in C++ with a GUI interface that needs to reproduce some mp3 depending on user's interactions. I need to reproduce the mp3 without blocking the program's flow. 
In order to save code, I decided to write a class to handle the mp3 reproducing and to reproduce it in a new thread, but I'm having problems when I need to stop the playing.

I know that libvlc have already some locking function, but the flow of the program stops when the mp3 is playing.

The mp3 starts correctly, but if I try to call the stop_mp3() function, I get a core dumped error.
The error is generated when I call the stop function from the secondpanel.cpp.

```
// replay.h
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

class rePlay
{
    public:
        rePlay();
        virtual ~rePlay();
        void play_mp3(const char*);
        void stop_mp3();
    protected:
        libvlc_instance_t *inst;
        libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
        libvlc_media_t *m;
    private:
};

// rePlay.cpp

#include "rePlay.h"
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mp3_mutex;
rePlay::rePlay()
{
    //ctor
}

rePlay::~rePlay()
{
    //dtor
}

void rePlay::play_mp3(const char* path){

    mp3_mutex.lock();
  // load the vlc engine
    inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    printf("apro il file %d\n", inst);
    // create a new item
    m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, path);
    // create a media play playing environment
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    // no need to keep the media now
    libvlc_media_release(m);
    // play the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
    printf("Done.\n");
}

void rePlay::stop_mp3(){
    mp3_mutex.unlock();
  // stop playing
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    // free the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);
}

// firstpanel.h

class firstpanel: public wxPanel
{
    public:
        firstpanel(wxWindow* parent, Isola02Frame*, wxWindowID id=wxID_ANY,const wxPoint& pos=wxDefaultPosition,const wxSize& size=wxDefaultSize);
        virtual ~firstpanel();
        void checkValue(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void check_cf(wxTimerEvent& event);
   rePlay *mp3_apertura_porta = new rePlay();    // <-- I DECLARED THE pointer here
        //(*Declarations(firstpanel)
        wxStaticText* assistenza;
        wxStaticText* first_panel;
        wxStaticText* identificazione;
        wxTextCtrl* tessera;
        //*)
...
}

// firstpanel.cpp
 std::thread second = std::thread([this]() noexcept {
        this->mp3_apertura_porta->play_mp3("/home/robodyne/Project/audio/scegli-rifiuto.mp3"); });
        second.join();

// secondpanel.cpp

void secondpanel::OnBitmapButton2Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
 firstpanel *ptr;
 ptr->mp3_apertura_porta->stop_mp3();
}
```

EDIT1: Thanks to @Ted Lyngmo, I used the libvlcpp library which seems to be async somehow and it works fine. The only problem is that I do not know how to call `mp.stopAsync()` from stop_mp3() to stop the audio file because variable `mp` is not global.

```
#include "rePlay.h"
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "vlcpp/vlc.hpp"

std::mutex mp3_mutex;

rePlay::rePlay()
{
    //ctor
}

rePlay::~rePlay()
{
    //dtor
}

void rePlay::play_mp3(const char* path){

    auto instance = VLC::Instance(0, nullptr);
    auto media = VLC::Media(instance, path, VLC::Media::FromPath);
    auto mp = VLC::MediaPlayer(media);
    auto mp.play();

#if LIBVLC_VERSION_INT >= LIBVLC_VERSION(4, 0, 0, 0)

#else
    mp.stop();
#endif
}

void rePlay::stop_mp3(){
     mp.stopAsync();  <-- variable mp is not global!
}
```

EDIT2:
I think the libvlcpp doesn't work well with GUI applications.
If I run it in a console application, I'm able to perform other operations in parallel, but when I execute it in the WxWidgets application, it blocks the flow.

This is the terminal console application:

```
    #include "vlcpp/vlc.hpp"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    if (ac < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << av[0] << " <file to play>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    auto instance = VLC::Instance(0, nullptr);
    auto media = VLC::Media(instance, av[1], VLC::Media::FromPath);
    auto mp = VLC::MediaPlayer(media);
    mp.play();
    for (int i=0; i < 10000000; i++){

    printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds( 10 ) );
#if LIBVLC_VERSION_INT >= LIBVLC_VERSION(4, 0, 0, 0)
    mp.stopAsync();
#else
    mp.stop();
#endif
}
```

the for() cycle works in parallel while the mp3 is playing.
The same doesn't happen if I use it with my application.

Comment: I added the mutex to protect the variables, but it still gives me core dump error.

Comment: `1.` `std::mutex` is usually not accessed directly: `std::unique_lock`, `std::lock_guard`, or `std::scoped_lock` (since C++17) manage locking in a more exception-safe manner.

`2.` The mutex and lock should be members of `rePlay`, the object that owns the thing you are protecting.

`3.` Your `lock()` and `unlock()` does not make sense. Look carefully at the examples for `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock`. 
`4.` You start the thread and `join()` directly. That way the main thread will wait for the background thread to finish directly. There's no need to run it in the background then.

Comment: `5.` looking at the documentation for libvlc it looks like `libvlc_media_player_play()` plays media in the background already. It "_Returns
0 if playback started (and was already started), or -1 on error._" - So it seems you shouldn't need to put it in a thread at all.

Comment: I already use it (libvlc_media_player_play()) but it blocks my program until the mp3 is not completed.

Comment: The documentation suggests that it shouldn't but it's very hard to say without being able to test it out. Perhaps if you shorten down your code to a bare minimum, but compilable example.  It's easier to help if one can copy/paste the code and just compile it without having to make any modifications.

Comment: Btw, have you seen [libvlcpp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlcpp)? "_C++ bindings for libvlc_" sounds promising.

Comment: Wow, thank you! libvlcpp really does the magic! It works! but I'm having problems to stop the playing by using stop_mp3() function since the variable mp is not global. How can I fix this? I edited my first topic to reflect the code.

Comment: Why the C tag? Please read the description of tags!

Comment: @MarcusBarnet That's great, but in order for people to be able to help more easily, make a short example that people can copy and compile as-is, without having to modify it at all.

Comment: I added a working example for a terminal console application. It works fine, but if I use the same code for my GUI application, the program's flow stops until the audio file is not finished. So it's the same problem again

Comment: @MarcusBarnet In that case it could be that you try doing things in the GUI application's GUI-thread. When responding to GUI-events, only the simplest tasks should be performed in the actual event handler. Anything taking longer than a few milliseconds is best done by worker threads. ... but it's still a bit confusing since the play functionality in libvlc looks threaded already. The libvlc forum has a lot of questions about these things I noticed - but unfortunately, I have no first hand experience with libvlc.

Comment: I can switch to another sound library, it is not mandatory for me to use libvlc. I just need to have the possibility to play and stop mp3 files with my GUI application. I spent all the day to find a solution but I found nothing, I'm desperate.